# querying data with sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have data in an sqlite db that contains the following columns:

```
date | name | id | code
```

all as  `TEXT` (I sourced it from a csv file) and I want to build a query that finds all `name`s that have `code` `ABC120` but not `ABC306` nor `ABC305` on the same `date` and `group` the result `GROUP BY name`. 
How do I do this?

Comment: I assume that by `group` you really mean `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `GROUP BY` you must `group by name, date` first and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause, but also you must use `DISTINCT` so the results do not contain duplicate names:

```
select distinct name
from tablename
group by name, date
having sum(code = 'ABC120') > 0 and sum(code in ('ABC305', 'ABC306')) = 0;
```

You can get the same results with `EXISTS`:

```
select distinct t.name
from tablename t
where t.code = 'ABC120'
and not exists (select 1 from tablename where name = t.name and date = t.date and code in ('ABC305', 'ABC306'))
```

Comment: to further tweak this (I used the first query you posted), how can I count the occurences by `name` ?

Comment: The occurrences of what? You mean the number of dates for each name?

Comment: yes, I mean number of days per name of presence of ABC120 but absence of ABC305 or ABC306.

Comment: Add another column after name: `select distinct name, count(*) over (partition by name) as days from .....`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `having`:

```
select date, name
from t
where code in ('ABC120', 'ABC306', 'ABC305')
group by date, name
having min(code) = 'ABC120' and max(code) = 'ABC120';
```

Note:  because of the three codes you chose, you could just use `max(code) = 120`.  However, that does not generalize to other code values.

Comment: Please review the updated question, the codes are not integers but strings

Comment: @BitFreak . . . That makes no difference.  Just make the comparisons strings (I updated the answer).

Comment: @BitFreak . . . I don't usually say this, but I think you should accept this answer.  It answered the question that you actually asked, it was first by quite a large margin of time, and the tweak to fix the types is very minor.